# Unknown Error (Python - VisualStudio Code)

Tags: python

```
hrs = int(input("How many hours do you want? "))
if hrs >= 24:
    day = hrs/24
    hrs = hrs
    if day == 1:
        print(hrs, "hours is equal to", day, "day")
    else:
        if day >= 7:
            wks = day / 7
            if wks == 1:
                print(day, "days is equal to", wks, "week")
            else:
                if wks >= 4:
                    mon = wks / 4
                    if mon == 1:
                        print(wks, "weeks is equal to", mon, "month")
else:
    if hrs == 1:
        print("You have 1 hour")
    else:
        print("You have", hrs, "hours")
```

For some reason when I try and use a number greater than 24 in `hrs = int(input("How many hours would you like? "))` it stops completely not giving me what the problem is.
[Here is what is shown in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fltwq.png)

I am using  VisualStudio Code to make this

Comment: for `hrs` set to 25, `day` would be 1.0 and not 1. You want `day = hrs//24`

Comment: The issue is not for ```day```, it is for the point after ```day == 1```. For some reason ```day == 1``` is working, ```else:
        if day >= 7:
            wks = day / 7
            if wks == 1:
                print(day, "days is equal to", wks, "week")
            else:
                if wks >= 4:
                    mon = wks / 4
                    if mon == 1:
                        print(wks, "weeks is equal to", mon, "month")``` 
is that part that isn't working.

Comment: please provide sample input, expected output and actual output. Also mention for example what you want when day is > 1 but < 7

Comment: Try providing additional documentation. It may be somewhat unclear as to what your code is trying to do (or what *you* intend it to do). This practice may help you not make as many logical errors (an error, in which, the code works, but not as the developer intended).

Answer (score 1):

try using Floor division // instaed of normal devision /

```
hrs = int(input("How many hours do you want? "))
if hrs >= 24:
    day = hrs//24
    hrs = hrs
    if day == 1:
        print(hrs, "hours is equal to", day, "day")
    else:
        if day >= 7:
            wks = day // 7
            if wks == 1:
                print(day, "days is equal to", wks, "week")
            else:
                if wks >= 4:
                    mon = wks // 4
                    if mon == 1:
                        print(wks, "weeks is equal to", mon, "month")
else:
    if hrs == 1:
        print("You have 1 hour")
    else:
        print("You have", hrs, "hours")
```

Comment: I will try that. Hopefully, it will fix my problem.

Comment: Was able to try it, the number being made into a floating number while the ```if``` was an integer caused the issue.

Comment: yes that's it , so the problem solved ?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with Visual Studio Code based on the information that you've provided in your post.

The first mistake that I could see was this:

```py
    day = hrs/24
    #...
    if day == 1:
```

Here, **day** will be exactly equal to **1** only when `hrs == 24`. For `hrs > 24`, **day** will always be a floating point number unless **hrs** is storing a multiple of **24**. Hence, the condition `day == 1` will never be *True*.
This also applies to the **else** block underneath, where you've written `wks = day / 7` and then `if wks == 1:`.

To resolve this, use the floor-division operator, `//`, which returns an integer value if both operands are integers.

The second thing that I noticed was that in line #4, you've written `hrs = hrs`. I believe you wanted to write `hrs = hrs % 24`, which assigns the remainder of **hrs** and **24** to **hrs** itself. So for **hrs = 25**, number of days = `hrs // 24` = **1**. And, number of hours = `hrs % 24` = **25 % 24** = **1** (remainder when 25 is divided by 24).

Now, on to the main question: ***Why did the console show no output, and why did the code terminate without doing anything?***

Well, notice that all the print statements in the code are under **if** or **else** conditions. If the conditions are never true, the print statements will not be executed at all!

Consider the case where `hrs = 25`. The first **if** block becomes *True* (`if hrs >= 24`) and hence gets executed. Note that the two print statements in the corresponding **else** block at lines *19* and *21* will not be executed now.

Since **hrs / 24** is a floating point number (not an integer, and *definitely* not equal to **1**), the statement `day == 1` is never *True* and hence its **if** statement never gets executed. So, the print statement in the `if day == 1:` block, `printf(hrs, "hours is equal to", day, "day")`, also does not get executed.
Now, the control goes to the **else** block below. `day >= 7` evaluates to *False*, since `hrs/24` is actually `1.08333...`.
Corresponding to this **if** (`if day >= 7:`), there is *no* **else**! So, when this **if** condition turns out to be *False*, the program terminates without doing anything!